# How to create an SVG tooltip with help of the Menucool JS plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have an SVG “map”, and I want to implement a simple tooltip when the mouse is hovered over a rectangle.

For the tooltip I want to use [this plugin](http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/javascript-tooltip).

Here is how I link SVG to HTML:

```
<object data="map.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="map" width="1840" height="940"></object>
```

The First Try was like this:

```
        var svgobject = document.getElementById('map'); 
        if ('contentDocument' in svgobject) {           
            var svgdom = $(svgobject.contentDocument);  
            $("#rect4578").tooltip.pop(this, '#ToltipContent');
        }
```

And the tooltip container is as follows:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="ToltipContent">
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <img src="img/img.jpg" style="float:right;" />
          Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

I also added the toolpip class to the rect4578 as it is explained on the plugin site. However it didn't work.

Then I tried to add the plugin invocation inside onmouseover attribute of the SVG rectangle.

```
onmouseover="tooltip.pop('#rect4578', '#ToltipContent')"
```

And also I got nothing.

However, if I change the opacity of the rectangle by using either of above described methods it works.

And the question is what is the right way to use this plugin to implement tooltip for the SVG?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't have access to your object, I used an svg from w3schools and it seemed to work fine. Here's what I did to get it to work:

```css
.hide {display:none;}
#object {width: 100px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto;}
#object svg {padding: 20px;}
div#mcTooltip h2 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 1;
}
#mcTooltip ul, #mcTooltip ol {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
div#mcTooltip {
    line-height: 16px;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #333;
    border-color: #bbb;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #aaa;
}
div#mcTooltip, div.mcTooltipInner {
    background-color: #eee;
}
div#mcTooltip a {
    color: #069;
}
div#mcTooltip a:hover {
    color: #333;
}
div#mcTooltipWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 9999999999;
    top: 0;
}
div#mcTooltip {
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.mcTooltipInner {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
div#mcTooltip, div#mcTooltip div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
div#mcttCo {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
}
div#mcttCo em, div#mcttCo b {
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.menucool.com/Content/widgets?v=pWIjgyLaRd3JgPu8kRMWTBEFhPIETaPsvP81TXLgnbE1"></script>
<div class="hide">
  <div id="toolTipContent">Tooltip text goes here</div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<object id="object" type="image/svg+xml" data="http://www.schepers.cc/svg/blendups/smiley.svg"><svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, '#toolTipContent', {position:2})" />
</svg><svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, '#toolTipContent', {position:2})" />
</svg><svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, '#toolTipContent', {position:2})" />
</svg></object>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, the star is not inside a tooltip?! If you go to the plugun's page amd look at 2. tooltip.pop(targetElement, '#contentElementId' [, options]) - when you hover those text a tooltip pops up. And a picture is inside that tooltip. Also, in your example I need to hover a text to see the picture, **but indeed I need to hover a SVG area (a square in my case) to see the tooltip**.

Comment: It actually is in a tooltip but the CSS was not included. I updated it so that it does have the CSS now and also included an example that I think better meets your description. Again, I don't have an SVG object to test so I'm doing the best with what I have. This article - http://benfrain.com/selecting-svg-inside-tags-with-javascript/ might also be of some value to you if you're trying to target the SVG content, but as far as I can tell targeting the object tag shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I need this tooltip appears when I hover some SVG area! NOT TEXT!  For an example you can use simple SVG rectangle (somewhere in codepen) or where you want! The problem is that I can not handle the hover event for SVG. I have the following svg object:
<rect   x="-158.052"
           y="616.745"
           width="32.89"
           height="3.4"
           id="rect136"
           fill="#908FB3" />
     <path.....
And I want use it's ID or class to invoke that tooltip on hover! Thank you!

Comment: Ok, no need to shout at me. ; )

Comment: I updated the example to have a square SVG in it. I'm not sure what else to do for you.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted. But I do not understand what was wrong with my try? You use here onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, '#toolTipContent', {position:1}). I was trying to use the same construction (see srart topic) and nothing worked! I'll examine your code! Well! Than you so much for the help and patience! :)

Comment: I'm not sure. I put the onmouseover attribute on the object and that seems to have worked.

Comment: Is it possible to add event tigger to this <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /> and not to <object> ? I have several <rect> shapes inside my <object> and I need a separate tooltip for each rect!

Comment: Yes, it appears that is possible (see updated snippet). Don't be afraid to experiment to find the answers to your questions - it's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem with your original approach is that the object tag does not support 'onmouseover' https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object. I am using the an img tag instead. This is a very minor change from the first answer.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('kiwi');
svg.onmouseover = function() {tooltip.pop(this, '#tooltip');}
```

```css
.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.menucool.com/Content/widgets?v=pWIjgyLaRd3JgPu8kRMWTBEFhPIETaPsvP81TXLgnbE1"></script>
<div class="">
  <img id="kiwi" height="200" width="200" src="http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg">
</div>
<div class="hide">
<span id="tooltip" >
    This is a tooltip.
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I know it's hard to tell running the code in the page because the window doesn't get big enough to show the message. Run the code snippet and then click full page.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, the previous snippet from ReLeaf demonstrates the correct solution!